# How to move files to Start Up Folder (Batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup

I need a batch file which will copy the C: drive of the user and copy it on the start up folder, thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly include what you have tried so far ,so that we may help you better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

move C:\ *.* C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

I think this will work, this might ask for admin permission, or it might just deny it